# FBAccount Kit Country Code Localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, account-kit

I am integrating the FB Account Kit into my app. But I have one issue with the country code. It seems that the localization is not working. I have added the AccountKit + AccountKitStrings.bundle into my app. What am i missing here?

I am running the app using the simulator (iOS 11)

[image: Sample Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and due to how I imported project I had not added "AccountKit.bundle" into my project.

In Alvins case AccountKitStrings.bundle should be "dragged and dropped" into project, not linked.